# Как обратиться к объекту в json

Tags: javascript, json

```js
const ex = JSON.parse('{"1":{"name":123},"2":{"name":123}}');
console.log(ex[0]);
```

Как обратиться к "1" или "2" в этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в JSON у вас не массив, а объект объектов, у которого нет ключа `'0'`, ваш код отображает `undefined`. А вот ключи `'1'` и `'2'` есть, поэтому к ним можно обращаться `ex[1]` или `ex['2']` (числовые ключи объектов автоматически преобразовываются в строки). В данном случае это будет обращение не к индексам массива, а к ключам объекта (единственно возможное для ключей в виде числа, поскольку сочетание `ex.1` синтаксически не разрешено).

Comment: Простите, в ответе были описки, исправил.